# compare date/time values in jQueryUI dialog(validation)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using a jQuery UI Dialog to capture data and update a database. I would like to validate the date/times fields to make sure that scheduledStart(datetime) is not greater than the scheduledStop (datetime).

If the validation is not met I would like to cancel the update and inform the user on the UI Dialog with a change to the css style. Based on my code below how can I add a validation to check my date boxes?

Here's what my code looks like to submit the data through .ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("<DIV></DIV>")
    .addClass("dialog")
    .attr("id", $(this).attr("data-dialog-id"))
    .appendTo("body")
    .dialog({
        title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
        width: dialogWidth,
        height: dialogHeight,
        close: function(){
            $(this).dialog("destroy");
            $(this).remove();
        },
        modal: true,
        cache: false,
        buttons: {
            "Save": function() {
                var recordId = $('#recordId').val();
                var scheduledStart = $('scheduledStart')convertToStandardDateTime($('scheduledStart').val());
                var scheduledStop = $('scheduledStop')convertToStandardDateTime($('scheduledStop').val());
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.action("SaveActivityDetails", "ActivtyDetails")",
                    Context: $(this),
                    Data: { recordId: recordId,
                            scheduledStart: (new Date(schededuledStart).toJSON(),
                            scheduledStop: (new Date(scheduledStop).toJSON() 
                          },
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function () {
                        $this.html("");
                        $this.dialog("close");
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorthrown)
                    {
                       //handle error
                    }
                });
             },
             "Cancel": function(){
                  $(this)dialog("close");
             }
          }
       })
       .load(this.href);
    });
});
```

Comment: Are `scheduledStart` and `scheduledStop` datepickers?

Comment: Can you provide [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Where is `$this` defined? You already set the context to `$(this)`, so using `this` in your callback functions will refer to `$(this)`. Also, don't use `html('')`, use `.empty()` instead.

Comment: The date values you are not datepickers. I am formatting them in MVC as custom formatted input: ddHHmmZ MMM yy

Comment: Unfortuanantley I cannot provide jsfiddle example. running in a secure evnironment has restrictions. In fact I had to manually copy my sample above by hand to paper to type it in.